# Desktop is unable to connect to X server for Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu

I would like to install a GUI desktop for my `Ubuntu 16.10`.

I refer to another [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53822/how-do-you-run-ubuntu-server-with-a-gui) in stackoverflow. What's wrong with it and do I have other easy options to launch a GUI desktop?

The installation and setup are:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
reboot
startx
```

---

#### STEP1:

```
xfwu:~/sandboxJDK$sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.373).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 170 not upgraded.
```

---

#### STEP2:

```
xfwu:~/sandboxJDK$sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell is already the newest version (3.20.4-0ubuntu2).
gnome-shell set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 170 not upgraded.
```

---

#### STEP3:

```
reboot
```

---

#### STEP4 (ERROR):

```
xfwu:~/sandboxJDK$startx     <--- even when I use sudo startx


X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.13.0-95-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux uta-PowerEdge-T630 4.8.0-54-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 24 10:21:44 UTC 2017 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-54-generic root=UUID=086b97e8-f914-43eb-a9fd-b09ccb5db609 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 07 September 2016  05:11:52AM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-1ubuntu6 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/home/xfwu/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Tue Jun 13 21:55:22 2017
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/xfwu/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

---

### error part:

```
Fatal server error:
(EE) parse_vt_settings: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (Permission denied)
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/xfwu/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console
```

Comment: You probably should have mentioned that you are apparently trying to do this over multiple SSH hops, as described in [How to start Ubuntu desktop after two times ssh to login my server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/926250/how-to-start-ubuntu-desktop-after-two-times-ssh-to-login-my-server)